# How to get the center coordinates for current view in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a image loading system and for it to work on mobile, I need to get coordinates of the center of canvas for my current view.
It should return the same result as if I mouse over the center.

I tried asking on fabric js github and they gave me this: 
but that result gave me back half my canvas height and width every time.
can anyone help me understand why?

```js
var myCenterCoordinates = fabric.util.transformPoint({
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
}, fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform));
```

If i mouse over the exact center of the canvas(i do have mouse position set up), I should see the same result of(x and y) if i call getcentercoordinates function

edit:
fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform)[4] and fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform)[5] gives you your current x and y coodinates for top left corner of your current view point, so we might be able to do something with that **strong text**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer:

```js
var zoom=canvas.getZoom()
function CenterCoord(){
   return{
      x:fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform)[4]+(canvas.width/zoom)/2,
      y:fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform)[5]+(canvas.height/zoom)/2
   }
}
```

to use this:

```js
var centerX=CenterCoord().x
var centerY=CenterCoord().y
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the center of the canvas

```
canvas.getCenter(); // Returns { top: number, left: number }
```

source: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getCenter